# Google Client Library for Java SDK and GDPR

Tags: google-api, google-drive-api, google-api-java-client

I am using the Google Client Library for Java SDK in my Android app to interface with Google Drive.

Do Google act as a Data Controller or Data Processor by using this SDK? I need to know if I need to store any data to show the user has consented to my app interfacing with Google Drive in line with GDPR.

I know I need to ask permission for personalised or non-personalised ads but the Google Drive SDK and GDPR stuff is driving me crazy.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

*Disclaimer I am not a legal type person this is my opinion from the guidelines that we have been given.  You should also seek independent legal advice relating to your status and obligations under the GDPR, as only a lawyer can provide you with legal advice specifcally tailored to your situation.*

For refrence I am going to quote from the following documents which as of my writing are the only thing Google has released with regard to GDPR that i am aware of ath this time

- [Google Cloud & the General Data Protection Regulation](https://cloud.google.com/security/gdpr/)
- [GOOGLE CLOUD & THE GDPR WHITEPAPER](https://services.google.com/fh/files/misc/gdprwhitepaperenglish.pdf)
- [Google Cloud & the General Data Protection Regulation (GDPR)](https://services.google.com/fh/files/misc/gdpronepagerweb.pdf)

> G Suite1
>    and Google Cloud Platform customers will typically act as
>   the data controller for any personal data they provide to Google in
>   connection with their use of Google’s services. The data controller
>   determines the purposes and means of processing personal data,
>   while the data processor processes data on behalf of the data
>   controller. Google is a data processor and processes personal data
>   on behalf of the data controller when the controller is using G Suite
>   or Google Cloud Platform.
>
> **Data controllers** are responsible for implementing appropriate
>   technical and organisational measures to ensure and demonstrate
>   that any data processing is performed in compliance with the GDPR.
>   Controllers’ obligations relate to principles such as lawfulness,
>   fairness and transparency, purpose limitation, data minimisation,
>   and accuracy, as well as fulfilling data subjects’ rights with respect
>   to their data.
>
> If you are a data controller, you may find guidance related to your
>   responsibilities under GDPR by regularly checking the website of
>   your national or lead data protection authority under the GDPR (as
>   applicable)2, as well as by reviewing publications by data privacy
>   associations such as the International Association of Privacy
>   Professionals (IAPP).
>
> You should also seek independent legal advice relating to your status
>   and obligations under the GDPR, as only a lawyer can provide you with
>   legal advice specifcally tailored to your situation. Please bear in mind
>   that nothing on this website is intended to provide you with, or should
>   be used as a substitute for legal advice.

Gsuite is Googles sweet of tools that being Drive, Calendar ... they are the data controller for the data behind the Google tools.

[Controller vs. Processor](https://www.gdpreu.org/the-regulation/key-concepts/data-controllers-and-processors/)

> (7) ‘controller’ means the natural or legal person, public authority, agency or other body which, alone or jointly with others, determines the purposes and means of the processing of personal data; where the purposes and means of such processing are determined by Union or Member State law, the controller or the specific criteria for its nomination may be provided for by Union or Member State law;
>
> (8) ‘processor’ means a natural or legal person, public authority, agency or other body which processes personal data on behalf of the controller;

**IMO**

If you are accessing a users data on Google Drive and changing it or doing anything with it then yes you are going to need to tell them what you are using their data for and log their consent. If you are saving their data anywhere then you are also going to have to give them the ability to delete that data.

There are some things you cant do for example if they want to delete all their files on drive thats not your responsibility that's Googles.  You are only responsible for the data thats on your system and what you have done with it.

Using googles client library IMO doesn't have much to do with GDPR its what you are doing with the data that they return that matters.   I did contact google a few months ago hoping to get some official guidelines with regard to GDPR and the client libraries.  I have not heard anything as of yet.

Comment: This was my thoughts also, app just merely adds an alternative UI to the users personal Google Drive. As I don't control the servers where the data is stored, I am not a data controller, and I'm not a data processor as I don't access any data that the user uploads to Google Drive. I will however, need to ask consent for Crash Reporting and Basic Analytics, though I hope to anonymize this information.

Comment: I think that having a project with Google you aggre to a data controller agreement with them.    if you are touching the data you are probably going to need to tell people what you are doing with it